# Setting up Freestyle 2 keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard

Has anyone had success getting the Kinesis Freestyle 2 keyboard running with Ubuntu 14.04 or a similar release?  Most of the keys work OK, but I can not get the volume controls working correctly.  In contrast, with my Goldtouch keyboard integrated volume controls work great.  The kinesis has other keys I would like to get operational like "Web", "Web Back" and "Web forward".

Thanks!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Please install tool evtest

> apt-get install evtest

After you must run

> sudo evtest

and press a keys to determine theis keycodes. If there is no keycodes probably you have an issue with firmware or linux driver.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can save this in .xbindkeysrc

```
"amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 3%-"
c:192
XF86Launch5

"amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 3%+"
m:0x0 + c:193
XF86Launch6

"xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness .7"
m:0x1 + c:192
#Shift XF86Launch5

"xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 1"
m:0x1 + c:193
```

This allows you to control audio with F1/F2 when 'fn' is not blue.

`sudo killall xbindkeys && xbindkeys`